# Does pgrep output ever include the parameters supplied to the process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ps

The snippet below (from an existing script) is used to check the `xvfb` processes and whether they are listening on a specific port:

```
  my_list=`pgrep -u $CurrentUserID -fl Xvfb | grep :${XVFBPORT}`
  process_list=`pgrep -fl Xvfb | grep :${XVFBPORT}`
```

The Xvfb process is started in the following format:

```
  Xvfb :619  -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc # i.e. in this case XVFBPORT is 619
```

Apparently this does not work as intended on Ubuntu since the output of `pgrep -fl Xvfb`
would give something like:

```
  4812 Xvfb
```

, without the ":619" at the end. Clearly, with some additional piping to `ps` this can be easily fixed.

Is there some other distro or configuration where `pgrep` would give the output as expected by the script?

Comment: What it's this other distro where pgrep works as intended? It could be different versions of pgrep that are installed by default.

Comment: @Braiam the script appears to have been tested against RHEL/SuSE but I did not have a chance to verify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recent version of `pgrep` from `procps-ng` has the `-a` option.

```
   -a, --list-full
          List  the  full  command line as well as the process ID.
```

So the `pgrep -afl Xvfb | grep 619` should print:

```
  4812 Xvfb :619  -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/mis
```

On my Debian Jessie (testing) this option is present, and the installed package is `procps-ng 3.3.9`, but I can't find a version when this option was introduced, perhaps the option is present in `procps-ng` and doesn't exist in `procps`.

Comment: I can confirm that the `-a` is there on `pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.4`.

Comment: The `-a, --list-full` option appears to be present on Ubuntu 14.04 (procps-ng 3.3.9) but absent on 13.10 (procps-ng 3.3.3) - however on 13.10 the default behavior for `-l` appears to be to print the whole command, including arguments. So it looks like the new option may have broken backward compatibility?

Comment: This might be the reason, I ran the script on Ubuntu 14.04 where it was indeed not working.

Comment: I can confirm that `pgrep -a` will give the intended output on Ubuntu 14.04, however this option is not shown in `pgrep --help`. Otherwise I would certainly have tried it.